# Многострочный input()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как можно сделать многострочный input(), ведь эта функция при вводе определённых символов а далее нажатии на Enter если программа состоит только из

```
a=input() 
print(a)
```

Просто завершится, так вот вопрос: можно ли сделать что бы input() завершался при нажатии на определённую кнопку, например, Esc

Comment: Обязательно заканчивать ввод именно какой-то клавишей? Может ли это быть какая-то особая строка (в т.ч. пустая), обозначающая конец ввода?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На Тостере был ответ на этот вопрос. Так что авторство не мое.
[Ссылка, чтобы поблагодарить автора](https://qna.habr.com/q/621743)

**Многострочный ввод в Python3**

```py
print("Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z ( windows ) to save it.")
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        line = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    contents.append(line)
```

**Многострочный ввод в Python2**

```py
print "Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z ( windows ) to save it."
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        line = raw_input("")
    except EOFError:
        break
    contents.append(line)
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что ''line'', это переменная, в которой хранится ввод, правильно?

Comment: @Alexander в `line` хранится только что введенная строка. А весь ввод хранится в списке `contents`.

Answer (score 8):

Не знаю способа закончить ввод какой-то определенной клавишей, но знаю другой способ:

```py
var = "\n".join(iter(input, ""))
```

В таком случае ввод закончится при нажатии enter на пустой строке.

---

Раз уж люди плюсуют, то, думаю, стоит объяснить код:
`iter(input, "")` будет `yield`'ить результат вызова функции `input` без аргументов, пока `input()` не вернёт пустую строку (`""`). Далее мы просто объединяем через `"\n"` все результаты из этого генератора.