# Выход из программы при вводе пустой строки (sys.stdin)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Перепробовал различные способы, но так и не понял как добиться завершения программы при вводе пустой строки. Я прочитал, что если строка `line` пустая, то можно выйти условием `if not line`, но это тоже не помогает.  Ловить ошибку при вводе ctrl+D  я не хочу, интересует именно завершение программы при вводе пустой строки.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это сделать?
Спасибо!

P.S. Код ниже

```
import sys
import os

with open('task1.txt', 'a') as some_file:
    for line in sys.stdin:
        if not line:
            print(f"Файл был успешно записан. Вы можете найти его по адресу {os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'task1.txt')}")
        else:
            some_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    if len(line) > 1:
        print(line)
    else:
        break

print("вышли")
```

вот так сможете выходить

вроде как ввод тоже при таком получении данных находится в строке, поэтому это надо учесть (что 1 символ всегда присутствует)

чтобы это более четко увидеть, можно выполнить такой код:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    if line == '\n':
        break

    # вывести введённую строку без последнего символа (который является символом '\n')
    print(line[:-1])

print("вышли")
```

Comment: break прервет цикл но программа продолжится.

Comment: @Kers, я данный пример привел просто чтобы показать что все дело в `'\n'`

Comment: Тогда извиняюсь все верно ))

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю более интересный способ:

```py
for line in iter(input, ''):
    print(f'Введена строка: {line}')
else:
    print('Была введена пустая строка, цикл закончен')
```

---

Объяснение:

- `iter(input, '')` - создаёт итератор, который на каждой итерации будет вызывать функцию `input()` и сверять полученное значение из функции с пустой строкой. Если из функции вернулась **не** пустая строка (т.е. что-то ввели в `input()`), то введёное значение будет обработано в теле цикла;
- Если в `input()` на предыдущем шаге ничего не ввели (вернулась пустая строка `''`), то, значит, цикл заканчивается и попадает в блок `else`, который выполняется после того, как цикл закончил свои итерации без прерывания (`break`).

Ссылки на документацию:

1. [`iter(object[, sentinel])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter)
2. [*break* and *continue* Statements, and *else* Clauses on Loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

---

На самом деле `else` здесь можно спокойно убрать, т.к. приведён просто для демонстрации. Т.е. без него код будет выглядеть:

```py
for line in iter(input, ''):
    print(f'Введена строка: {line}')
print('Была введена пустая строка, цикл закончен')
```

Comment: Практически дубликат ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1069413/324059.

Comment: Очень познавательно! Больше спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

У вас уже есть проверка на пустую строку просто допишите туда exit() и проверку на перевод строки:

```py
import sys
import os

with open('task1.txt', 'a') as some_file:
    for line in sys.stdin:
        if not line or line == '\n': # перевод строки
            print(f"Файл был успешно записан. Вы можете найти его по адресу {os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'task1.txt')}")
            exit() # выход из программы
        else:
            some_file.write(line)
```

В данном случае вы получите выход из программы даже если после цикла есть продолжение.