# Как сделать многострочное поле ввода в терминале?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне надо сделать многострочное поле ввода `input()`, но также чтобы я мог перемещаться между строками используя стрелочки на клавиатуре, используя Python.

Comment: Не является дубликатом [Многострочный input()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1069402/1365), т.к. там требуется просто возможность многострочного ввода (без перемещения по редактируемому тексту), и нет ответа, который бы отвечал на данный вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Встроенных средств для многострочного ввода с редактированием и перемещением стрелками внутри вводимого текста в Python нет.

Можно использовать сторонние модули, например модуль [`prompt_toolkit`](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit) (установка `pip instal prompt_toolkit`).

Пример многострочного ввода (завершение ввода <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> или <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>,
или <kbd>Esc</kbd>, потом <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
from prompt_toolkit import prompt


answer = prompt('Give me some input: ', multiline=True)
print('You said:', answer)
```

Документация по `prompt` (кроме многострочного ввода можно реализовать автодополнение, подсказки вариантов, подсветку синтаксиса, валидацию ввода, хранение истории ввода и т.д.): [Asking for input (prompts)](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/asking_for_input.html)

Answer (score 0):

Уже был похожий вопрос, так что авторство ответа не моё. [Ссылка, чтобы поблагодарить автора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1069411/296823).

**Многострочный ввод в Python3**

```
print("Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z ( windows ) to save it.")
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        line = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    contents.append(line)
```

**Многострочный ввод в Python2**

```
print "Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z ( windows ) to save it."
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        line = raw_input("")
    except EOFError:
        break
    contents.append(line)
```

Comment: Не нужно дублировать ответы внутри ru.stackoverflow.com. Для подобных случаев есть механизм закрытия вопросов как дубликатов.

Comment: Ну и кстати код не делает того, что требуется в вопросе