# Как сделать чтобы в input() могли присутсвовать enter-ы?

Tags: python, json

У меня есть простенький код:

```
API_URL = input("API url: ")
API_JSON = input("json data: ")
requests.post(API_URL, json=API_JSON)
```

Код должен отправлять на введённым пользователем `url`-запрос с введеным `json`-кодом, но как только я пытаюсь ввести `json`-код с `enter`-ами, он сразу пропускает код `input()`-а и переключается на другие строки, а `json`- код не работает без `enter`-ов.

Comment: Может, подойдёт Shift + Enter?

Comment: Dark Space, не помогло

Comment: пусть пользователь вводит джейсон без новой строки

Comment: Эникейщик, джсон не может так работать, по крайней мере на примере дискорд вебхука

Comment: Ну придумайте какой-то символ специальный или сочетание символов и заменяйте его на перевод строки. Да и странно, что у вас без переводов строки то не работает, можно и в одну строку весь жсон написать при желании.

Comment: Напишите юзеру, что для завершения ввода нужно ввести "такой то символ" и в цикле собирайте строку. Появится символ в конце ввода - проверьте, что он не часть жсон и вот вам вся строка жсон

Comment: Вот это не оно? [Многострочный input](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1069413/225714)

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z ( windows ) to save it.")
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        line = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    contents.append(line)
```